# Caml Query for Sharepoint list columns

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml

+items.text+Value Type='Text'>

I have 4 Column i want to populate my data with respect to the first column selected as checkboxlist is fetching the first column of data

Comment: I have 4 columns in list column 1 is "Title"  which i am using in checkboxlist so when any checkbox is checked I want to create folders in a tree view dynamically.

Comment: Title Key Level2 level3 level4 are the folders

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install CAML Query builder from [here](http://www.u2u.be/Software)

You just write your logic and your caml query will be built automatically.

Very helpful tool for caml queries.